UIHostingController NavigationBar glitches when swipe gesture
It seems like an Apple bug because it only happens in newer devices like the iPhone 15 Pro.
Using a coordinator as UINavigationController sets the UIViewController as the viewControllers. In the UIViewController, I then put the title and add UIHostingController to the parent.
When I scrolled a little bit (the large title became a small title), and tapped into a second page, now if I tapped the back button, it behaved as expected, however, if I swiped back, the small title dropped and became the large title, which is unexpected.
the screen recording
the code is as follows:
class Coordinator: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = ViewController()
        viewControllers = [vc]
        vc.delegate = self
        
    }
}
extension Coordinator: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func viewControllerDidTap(_ viewController: ViewController) {
        let vc = ViewController()
        pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewControllerDidTap(_ viewController: ViewController)
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Profile"
        createListView()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

}
extension ViewController {

    private func createListView() {
        let listView = ListView { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            delegate?.viewControllerDidTap(self)
        }
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: listView)

        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)

        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
struct ListView: View {

    var tapHandler: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                tapHandler?()
            }
        }
    }
}

